# How do you do "pre-groupings" in Excel Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

Power Query newbie here, if this won't work just let me know
I get a big report that looks like this (there's other rows, but I'll just use this)

| First Name | Last Name | Sales Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | row | 123-1 |
| Second | row | 123-1 |
| First | row | 123-2 |
| Second | row | 1234-55 |

Basically, I want to tell Power Query that I want everything in the 123- group to be together, then the codes in the 1234- group and so on and so on. But I want to be able to edit that 123- group to have more codes in the future (i.e. the next report has 123-4).

I'm trying to use group by and split, but I don't know how to tell query that I want to make my own mini lists first for it to split after.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps add a custom column with the part of the Sales code prior to the hyphen; then group on that custom column.

Comment: Hi peter and Ron, thanks for your help! Sorry for the delayed response, using custom conditional columns was the ticket. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In PowerQuery you go to *Add Column* - *Extract* - *Text Before Delimiter* and then enter the "-" sign. With that new column selected you go to *Home* - *Group by* and then define your aggregation. Since you don't have any numbers in your table only counting the rows makes sense.

Here's a sample M-code

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcspPUtJRKsovB5KGRsa6hkqxOtFKwanJ+XkpWCTcMouKS1DEjXBoMNE1NVWKjQUA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"First Name" = _t, #"Last Name" = _t, #"Sales Code" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
        Source,{{"First Name", type text}, {"Last Name", type text}, {"Sales Code", type text}}),
    #"Inserted Text Before Delimiter" = Table.AddColumn(
        #"Changed Type", "Sales Group", each Text.BeforeDelimiter([Sales Code], "-"), type text),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(
        #"Inserted Text Before Delimiter", {"Sales Group"}, {{"Count of Rows", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

The result will look like this:

[image]